# Assigning background images to a querySelectorall function JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

so I am trying to assign background images to the div without the use of CSS and writing it like 6 times so this is the HTML:

```js
var arImages = ["Chicken_BannerIcon2-1.png", "Chicken_BannerIcon3-1.png",
  "Chicken_BannerIcon4-1.png", "Chicken_BannerIcon5-1.png",
  "Chicken_BannerIcon6-1.png", "Chicken_BannerIcon7-3.png",
]

var menu = document.querySelectorAll(".grid > div::before")

let bg = arImages.map((element) => {
  return element;
})

let newArray = Array.from(menu).map((item) => {
  var img = document.createElement("img")
  img.src = bg
  item.appendChild(img)
  return item
})
```

```html
<div class="grid pt-3">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
</div>
```

Comment: `bg` is the same as arImages its a new array with all the values of arImages

Comment: if you want to map you can do .map((item,index)=>{ ..... }). use the index to add it to get the arImages individually instead of assigning probably depending on what you are trying to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your `querySelectorAll` didn't find anything because of the `::before`, so I've removed that
2. The `img.src = bg` didn't work because `bg` was the same as `arImages` and you'll need a single index instead of the complete array (see point 5)
3. I've replace the `map` to a `forEach` since you don't need a return value
4. Removed the `Array.from` because `forEach` exists on the nodelist
5. Using the `index` provided by the foreach to get the index from `arImages`

```js
var arImages = [
  "Chicken_BannerIcon2-1.png", "Chicken_BannerIcon3-1.png", 
  "Chicken_BannerIcon4-1.png", "Chicken_BannerIcon5-1.png", 
  "Chicken_BannerIcon6-1.png", "Chicken_BannerIcon7-3.png", 
]

var menu = document.querySelectorAll(".grid > div")

menu.forEach((item, index) => {
    var img = document.createElement("img")
    img.src = arImages[index]
    item.appendChild(img);
})
```

```html
<div class="grid pt-3">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You don't even need the `Array.from`. `forEach` works perfectly well with nodelists (I think it's the only array method that does).

Comment: Thank you for the help, but I have seen where I went wrong

Comment: No problem, will do

Comment: The only other thing is these are meant to background images for each div @0stone0.

Answer (score 0):

At first, remove the `::before` selector.

Then you just need to add the index to your js and then referencing that to your images array like so:

```js
var arImages = [
  "Chicken_BannerIcon2-1.png",
  "Chicken_BannerIcon3-1.png",
  "Chicken_BannerIcon4-1.png",
  "Chicken_BannerIcon5-1.png",
  "Chicken_BannerIcon6-1.png",
  "Chicken_BannerIcon7-3.png"
];
document.querySelectorAll(".grid > div").forEach((item, index) => {
  var img = document.createElement("img");
  img.src = arImages[index];
  item.appendChild(img);
});
```

```html
<div class="grid pt-3">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need to predefine your HTML items. You can programmatically [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over the array and create an array of HTML strings using the data from each element, [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) it up, and then apply that complete HTML string to the container.

```js
const arImages=['https://dummyimage.com/50x50/efefef/000000&text=Image1','https://dummyimage.com/50x50/efefef/000000&text=Image2','https://dummyimage.com/50x50/efefef/000000&text=Image3','https://dummyimage.com/50x50/efefef/000000&text=Image4','https://dummyimage.com/50x50/efefef/000000&text=Image5','https://dummyimage.com/50x50/efefef/000000&text=Image6'];

// Just select the container
const grid = document.querySelector('.grid');

// `map` over the array, and for each element return
// an HTML string where the element has background that
// matches the element
const html = arImages.map((img, i) => {
  const style = `background-image: url(${img}); width: 50px; height: 50px`;
  return `<div style="${style}">${i + 1}</div>`;
});

// Because `map` returns an array we `join` it up
// into one string, and then add it to the container
grid.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', html.join(''));
```

```html
<div class="grid pt-3"></div>
```

Additional documentation

- [Template/string literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)
- [`insertAdjacentHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML)